# Error Running JSP on Jetty Server v 9.2.2

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, configuration, jetty

I have installed Jetty web server v 9.2.2 for using it with Netbeans for Java web development:

Now when I run the project I get following error:

```
WARNING: ** Unable to continue, required dependency missing. [jsp-impl/${jsp-impl}-jstl]
WARNING: ** As configured, Jetty is unable to start due to a missing enabled module dependency.
WARNING: ** This may be due to a transitive dependency akin to spdy on npn, which resolves based on the JDK in use.
Missing referenced dependency: jsp-impl/${jsp-impl}-jstl

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
Java Result: -6
```

I followed the configuration guide for enabling jsp support and edited jsp.ini file in start.d folder of ${jetty.home}:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jsp.html

but then I get error that:

```
Unrecognized argument: "[depend]" in C:\jetty\work\JettyServerInstance\jettybase\start.d\jsp.ini

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
Java Result: -6
```

What could possibly be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Djsp-impl=apache` or `-Djsp-impl=glassfish` to your command line.

or

Add `jsp-impl=apache` or `jsp-impl=glassfish` to your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

This is bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: thanx for the reply, but I am still getting the same error, I am using the latest version of Jetty, i.e. v 9.2.2

Comment: Resolved the issue by just changing the Jetty Server version from v9.2.2 to v9.1.5.